# Suggested Words for Query using ColdFusion / jQuery

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion query the leverages the full-text capabilities of MySQL (IN BOOLEAN MODE).  I am NOT using verity.  The search page quickly returns the results based on EXACT word matching leveraging Boolean search queries.   But I have no way of suggesting corrected spelling.

My question is this.  Is there a way to provide a suggested word list, like in Google (based on similarities or commonly mis-spelled word), once the query is submitted?

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table where you can store the everyday search queries in a column of string data.

When a user starts searching, run a 'like' condition on this table and show the matched values as 'auto-suggest' for your input area.

You can add more spice to this, by extending the functionality. Every time a user searches and chooses a particular 'searched string' give it a rank +1. Here on, the best ranked ones gets the top priority in your 'like' query.

For the 'did you mean...' also, the 'like' query with most ranked can be shown. A complex approach would be to use the spell checker algorithm as explained [here](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) to find similar words and run a like query with them to get the top ranked one again.